# spring mvc 4: parse String to java.time.LocalDate using property format annotation

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, spring-4

In a DTO, I can get a date string converted to a `java.util.Date`, using the `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat` annotation:

```
class myDTO {
     @JsonFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")
     private Date theDate;
     // accessors, etc...
}
```

Not so when the property is of type `java.util.LocalDate`...

How do I make it work?

Using `jackson-databind-2.4.1`

Thanks!

Comment: Use `JavaTimeModule` module. Take a look at [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8), [Jackson Serialize Instant to Nanosecond Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345200/jackson-serialize-instant-to-nanosecond-issue), [Spring Boot Jackson date and timestamp Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55256567/spring-boot-jackson-date-and-timestamp-format)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Jackson date and timestamp Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55256567/spring-boot-jackson-date-and-timestamp-format)

Comment: @MichałZiober, thanks. Could you provide XML config that achieves this?

Comment: If you use `Spring Boot` it should pick up `JavaTimeModule` module automatically if it will be on class path. So, adding dependency would be a good start. If not, you need to create custom `ObjectMapper` instance and register module manually. Take a look at [Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) for an example. Which version of `Spring` do you use?

Comment: Alas, this question specifically relates to `spring-mvc` (v4. See title/tags), not `spring-boot`. Thanks for the links, but those look like they're `spring-boot`-specific.